# Should 'new AWS.S3' instance be a global variable or should a separate AWS.S3 instance be placed in each route?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-sdk

**Environment:** Node.js, Express, AWS-SDK

Currently my `AWS.S3` instance is a global variable sitting at the top of my middleware.

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
    accessKeyId: process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region: process.env.S3_REGION
});

app.get('/page1', function(req, res) {
});

app.get('/page2', function(req, res) {
});
```

I use `AWS.S3` in a variety of different routes.
I use the `deleteObject()` and `upload()` methods asynchronously in the background.  However I also use the `headObject()` with `async/await` because I need the result before I can move to the next action.

In order to avoid some type of `S3` collision or other unexpected problem should I place a new instance of `AWS.S3` at the top of each piece of middleware? I'm not sure if this necessary or not.  For comparison with `Mongoose` it takes just one statement `mongoose.connect()` and a pool of 5 connections opens up that can be used by every route in the app.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    const s3 = new AWS.S3({
        apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
        accessKeyId: process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        region: process.env.S3_REGION
    });

});

app.get('/page2', function(req, res) {

    const s3 = new AWS.S3({
        apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
        accessKeyId: process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        region: process.env.S3_REGION
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to share a single S3 instance with multiple functions. The S3 library (indeed node.js itself) already can handle multiple connections to S3. A single instance will use less RAM and reduce potential for bugs in case you need to change something (it prevents needing to change it all over the place).

Indeed, ideally a single S3 instance should be used in all your files. I normally initialize S3 in its own module then export the instance.

Example:

```
// lib/s3.js

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
 apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
    accessKeyId: process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region: process.env.S3_REGION
});

module.exports = s3;
```

Then in my other code:

```
const s3 = require('./lib/s3');   

app.get('/page1', function(req, res) {
});

app.get('/page2', function(req, res) {
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the great info.  This article talks about setting that maximum number of sockets.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/node-configuring-maxsockets.html  At the bottom it says, "If the maxSockets value is not defined or is Infinity, the SDK assumes a maxSockets value of 50."  Do you know if this applies to AWS-SDK in general or am I looking at the wrong info?

Comment: That's an AWS SDK thing. Additional requests would probably be queued. The maxSockets is the number of parallel operations you can do on S3.